# A question on modifiers

Tags: grammar

"Voldemort turned his scarlet eyes upon Harry, laughing a high, cold, mirthless laugh."

Grammatically, the sentence is implying that Harry is laughing, right? I was reviewing modifiers, and the rule stated that a modifier must be placed near the word it modifies.

How about..."Voldemort, turning his scarlet eyes upon Harry, laughed a high, cold, mirthless laugh."

Comment: It was Voldemort who laughed. If the sentence had meant to indicate it was Harry who laughed, it could be written this way: *Voldemort turned his scarlet eyes upon Harry,* ***who laughed*** *a high, cold, mirthless laugh.* Modifiers and pronouns are generally closest to what they modify—but they certainly don't have to be. It's just an overall principle that helps avoid misinterpretation.

Comment: Voldemort has cast the dread [*Super Monte Determinatio*](https://www.google.com/search?q=Latin+for+%22dangling+modifier%22&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS724US727&oq=Latin+for+%22dangling+modifier%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.11127j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), one of the more peculiar befuddlement spells and potions.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to start by saying if some form of literature told you that it **must** be near the word it is modifying... it is wrong. There can be many cases of this not being true.

First lets deconstruct this sentence to its basic components.

Subject -  Voldemort -  He is performing the action.

Action verb - turned - That is what Voldemort is doing.

*Object - "his scarlet eyes" - really "eyes" are the object and "his" & "scarlet" are modifiers.

Prepositional phrase - "upon Harry" - upon is a preposition with its object being harry.

So here is where you have to understand that harry is an object of upon. **Objects cannot perform actions only subjects can**. Example "He ran to the store that caught on fire", The "store" **caught nothing**, the store is an object of what "he" ran to, in this case "that" is the subject. This is why harry is not the one laughing in this sentence, but why is Voldemort?

Because of that comma, it separates the sentence into its independent and dependent clauses. "Voldemort turned his scarlet eyes upon Harry." is completely fine by itself. "laughing a high, cold, mirthless laugh." **NO NO NO NO** there is no subject here therefore this is a sentence fragment and incorrect! so this fragment depends on the first part. It has a predicate, all it needs is a subject. The only subject available to it is Voldemort as Harry, even if close, is an object therefore cannot take on a predicate.

I hope that helped. Please if you have any questions then ask. you have a wonderful day!

Comment: So...the sentence is not grammatically correct; however, the object cannot contain a predicate, therefore the predicate refers to the subject?

Comment: @austingae Oh no! sorry if I made you assume the sentence was incorrect. The whole point was to show you the sentence is correct! Sorry for failing you. Yes, objects cannot have a predicate, so yes that predicate is referring to the only subject which is Voldemort.

Comment: I also believe Voldemort is the one laughing, but you wouldn't want to use the term "predicate" in referring to "laughing" because "laughing" is a participle here (basically, a verbal adjective) that is modifying either Voldemort or Harry. Because Voldemort is the subject of the sentence and the way the sentence reads, I am inclined with you to apply the participle to him as well. If the sentence read, "Voldemort turned his eyes on Harry, shivering in the corner" I'd probably think "shivering" would be modifying Harry, instead.

Comment: @joseph Thank you for the correction, I realize my mistake with the naming. On the subject of assuming. I that would be more a quirk of the English language rather than a grammatical mistake. I would say the author should have just restructured the sentence.

Comment: Are you sure? Consider *“Harry saw Sally giving her dog a new bone.”* What do you think the subject of *giving* is there, Harry or Sally? What do you imagine the object of *saw* to be here?

Comment: Well think about it like this. Split the sentence into two. If you are implying sally is the subject of giving then it is a complete sentence as it has subject and predicate. So if we Separate it we get "sally giving her dog a new home". Do you see how that sentence doesn't sound right? because you are treating giving like it is in its present progressive when it is actually a verbal if I am not mistaken. "Sally is giving her dog a new home" is correct. But when we combine them again we get. "Harry saw Sally is giving her dog a new home" Which doesn't make sense. @tchrist

Comment: @tchrist so that would make "sally giving her dog a new home" an object phrase making the entire thing an object of saw. so try making the phrase <sally giving her dog a new home> a subject of any sentence without making it proper.

Comment: “Object phrase” is not a term familiar to me. But your wish is my command: *Sally giving her dog a new home was the last thing Harry wanted to see.*

Comment: Wait... I didn't even think before I typed that... It is quite late where I am sorry for me being absolutely idiotic. Of course you can turn that into a subject, phrases are grammatical objects there for they can hold a state if you use a copula. And I don't even know what an object phrase is either... I think I meant gerund phrase. I probably need to rest because now I am making up terms. But did you understand what I meant about separating it and it not being a complete sentence? That should still stand true, unless I made another huge error in my logic. I wouldn't be surprised.